# How do I pass a custom Router to a service in a Symfony Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, routes

In my Bundle I use a SessionHandler service under FooBundle/Service/SessionHandler.php

This gets passed a customized Router which extends the Symfony Router:

```
use FooBundle/Routing/Router
    (...)
    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, Router $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $router->getContainer();
        $this->defaultLogoutHandler = new DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler($httpUtils);
        parent::__construct($httpUtils, $options);
    }
```

This did work back in Symfony 2.1

With 3.1 I get an Exception:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to FooBundle\Service\SessionHandler::__construct() must be an instance of FooBundle\Routing\Router, instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router given

Here is what my services.xml looks like:

`<!-- SessionHandler -->
    <service id="foo.sessionhandler" class="FooBundle\Service\SessionHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="security.http_utils" />
        <argument type="collection" id="options" />
        <argument type="service" id="router" />
    </service>`

So how do I get this service to use my customized router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `router` currently being passed is the Symfony Router and hence Symfony `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router` is given.

You must define your customised `Router` (`FooBundle/Routing/Router`) as a service and pass it's service id to the arguments list of service `foo.sessionhandler` to replace `<argument type="service" id="router" />`.

Comment: I see. So in the service.xml I'd have to define something like the for the SessionHandler in my Question above. The constructor for the Router asks for a container, which I know how to provide, but it also asks for a resource to load. How would I provide that for the Router service?

Comment: What is that resource? If it's something that is being loaded from doctrine, you can provide `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`.

Comment: I don't know what exactly it is, the commet from the Symfony Routers description just says `@param mixed  $resource  The main resource to load`

Comment: The easiest way to know is try to dump and see what resource object you get. Then check if that resource is available in a service.